# Hide a python server ip

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I would like to know if there is any way to make a python socket server ip hidden (using tor or proxies).

I know that you can make a client-side request over tor but I would like to be able to connect to the server without having to know his real ip adress (with a .onion adress for exemple)

The code will be accessible so encrypting the ip will may not be the solution.

My server code right now:

```
import socket


s = socket.socket()
host = "192.168.1.1"
port = 9999
print(f"server will start on host:{host}")
s.bind((host, port))
print("Server is bond !")
s.listen(1)
client, address = s.accept()
print(address, "connected")
```

My client code:

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '192.168.1.18'#  ip address of the server (that I would like to hide)
port = 80

try:
    s.connect((host, port))
    print("connected !")
except:
    print("error !")
```

Comment: What do you mean by hide? encrypt ?

Comment: Setup a proxy at a location you can disclose. But that's not a Stack Overflow topic.

Comment: You may be looking for tor [hidden services](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services).